# RxBluetoothKit with RxAndroidBle

Tags: swift, rx-android, rxandroidble, rxiosble

I am currently developing a xplattform Android/iOS App and evaluating, if iOS devices using *RxBluetoothKit* can communicate with Android devices running *RxAndroidBle* from [Polidea GitHub](https://github.com/Polidea)?

I already looked through the FAQ, Stackoverflow and Gitter questions, but could not find a precise answer.

I am quite sure, that a communication should be possible, but I'd love to have a confirmation from someone who is not a total noob in BLE like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BLE(Bluetooth Low Energy)` is a network technology designed by `Bluetooth SIG` and adopted by many platforms (`iOS`, `Android`, `Windows`, etc). The technology is independent of the `Reactive Extensions(Rx)` frameworks you mentioned. The `Rx` frameworks just supply a `FRP(Functional Reactive Programming)` interface to the technology. So `RxBluetoothKit` is basically a wrapper around `Apple`'s `Core BlueTooth` framework, providing the `Rx` features. According to `Wikipedia`, `BLE` is supported by `iOS 5` and later as well as `Android 4.3` and later. You can find the specification here [Bluetooth Core Specification V4.0](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications)